# How can i handle edited strings efficiently?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

i've noticed something within VS/C# thats a bit of a grey area for me? was hoping someone could explain. i've followed guides online to set up a Treeview Control, and copied and pasted the code that said it handled the label and put it through certain validations as you'll see below, however the desired result is not quite there.

What is happening:
it seems as though the code is only checking the edit, and not the label? because if the label isn't changed, i start to see the messageboxes come up even though, the value isn't null, the length is > 0 AND does NOT contain special characters.. which leads me to beleive its only checking the new value?

```
        private void TreeSlabs_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Label != null)
            {
                if (e.Label.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (e.Label.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '@', '.', ',', '!' }) == -1)
                    {

                        // Stop editing without canceling the label change.
                        e.Node.EndEdit(false);   


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Cancel the label edit action, inform the user, and 
                            place the node in edit mode again. */
                        e.CancelEdit = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid tree node label.\n" +
                           "The invalid characters are: '@','.', ',', '!'",
                           "Node Label Edit");
                        e.Node.BeginEdit();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                /* Cancel the label edit action, inform the user, and 
                    place the node in edit mode again. */
                e.CancelEdit = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid tree node label.\nThe label cannot be blank",
                   "Node Label Edit");
                e.Node.BeginEdit();
            }
        }
```

could someone verify my theory?

What would be the better way around this code to test the value? i know the values going into the tree are "validated" as per the conditions above.. so really if the label hasn't changed, it should still allow the edit but it wont...?

Any advice, as always greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance to SO community.

Jack

Comment: What's your question? Are you trying to figure out what the code is doing or do you have a specific requirement?

Comment: I don't know if you copied the code as it was, anyway, change the first condition: `if (e.Label == null) return;`. The `else` part belongs to the outer `if` condition, which needs to be `if (e.Label.Trim().Length > 0) { if (e.Label.IndexOfAny(...) ... } else { e.CancelEdit = true; ... }`. The inner `if/else` condition is OK,

Comment: What message box is shown exactly? And are you sure your validation process is correct? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, thanks to those that responded (been at work all day)

So, can confirm, its the final exception "null" because it only returns the "label cant be blank" MessageBox.

What am i trying to acheive? iliterally just want to enable editing of the captions but ensuring the value isn't incorrect.. i've not approached this in the best way to be honest. (if you can't tell, i'm new)

Eventually, i want to be able to pull all the data out from the treeview, and have it converted into a HTML Texpart Email body neatly.